# Calling Dropdownlist by id in global functions page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, dropdown, getelementbyid, runatserver

I'm working on a project in asp.net with vb.net.

I had this function underneath in the file team.aspx.vb

```
Private Sub fillPFileRelationTypes()
        Dim intOfficeCategoryTypeId = fGetOfficeCategoryTypeId()
        ddl_RelationType.Items.Clear()
        ddl_RelationType.Items.Add("title","value")
        ddl_RelationType.Items.Add("title2","value2")
End Sub
```

It worked fint in combination with the frontend in file team.aspx. Which is no more than this:

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_PFileRelationType" runat="server">
            </asp:DropDownList>
```

But now I want to get all my functions in a global Functions.aspx.vb file. So it's not directly in the backend of the same page (as in team.aspx vs. team.aspx.vb) This means calling the dropdownlist by the id in the backend doesn't work anymore.

How can I call my dropdownlist with id="ddl_RelationType" in a file not related to the file where this one is declared?

I was thinking of the underneath but it's not entirely correct

```
Private Sub fillPFileRelationTypes()
            Dim intOfficeCategoryTypeId = fGetOfficeCategoryTypeId()
            Dim myInput As HtmlInputControl = CType(e.Item.FindControl("ddl_RelationType"), HtmlInputControl)
            myInput .Items.Clear()
            myInput .Items.Add("title","value")
            myInput .Items.Add("title2","value2")
    End Sub
```

Comment: Why you want to move a method that relates to the current page to a "global-functions-aspx"?

Comment: Pass it as parameter... If this function is used only for one dropdown, then I don't see a reason to put it in the global file. Private Sub fillPFileRelationTypes(byVal dd As DropDownList)

Comment: As it will grow I might want to re-use the code for other dropdowns in other pages throughout this project. And it's starting to get a realy big project and we're working on it with a team so I want it to be very clear for everyone where they can find what they're looking for

Comment: @ManuelvandenNotelaer usually, if this is a dropdown that is used at multiple place, you would create your own by inheritance.